# Export ArcGIS spatially enabled dataframe to feature class

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pandas, arcgis-python-api, spatially-enabled-dataframe

I'm working to develop a tool that converts JSON data pulled from an API into a feature class to be stored in an ESRI file geodatabase. I'm currently testing the functionality in a Jupyter notebook within an ArcGIS Pro project but my goal is to eventually convert my script into a geoprocessing tool that can be used by non-developer users. However, I've gotten stuck in the prototype phase and cannot figure out if I am running into a bug or if there is an issue with my code.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import arcpy
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor, GeoSeriesAccessor
import pandas as pd

# pull public geojson data from socrata

r = requests.get('https://data.bayareametro.gov/resource/ufzj-38uk.json')
j = r.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j)

# Convert to Spatially Enabled Pandas Dataframe

sedf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_df(df, geometry_column='shape')

# Export Spatially Enabled Pandas Dataframe to FGDB Feature Class

sedf.spatial.to_featureclass(location='equity_priority_areas_2020')
```

This is the error message I received:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [22]:
Line 5:     sanitize_columns=True)

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo\_accessor.py, in to_featureclass:
Line 2388:  has_m=has_m,

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo\_io\fileops.py, in to_featureclass:
Line 853:   df.columns = original_columns

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py, in __setattr__:
Line 5478:  return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

File pandas\_libs\properties.pyx, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__:
Line 66:    

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py, in _set_axis:
Line 670:   self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py, in set_axis:
Line 221:   f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 42 elements, new values have 41 elements
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is what I tried to resolve the issue:

I reviewed the GeoAccessor class method [to_featureclass](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.GeoAccessor.to_featureclass) API reference and tried to set the path to the File Geodatabase explicitly as well as provide explicit values for the `has_z`, `haz_m`, and `sanitize_columns` parameters as shown below and got the same error message.

```
sedf.spatial.to_featureclass(location='Z:\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\Socrata_to_ArcGIS\Socrata_to_ArcGIS.gdb\equity_priority_areas_2020', 
                             overwrite=True, 
                             has_z=False, 
                             has_m=False, 
                             sanitize_columns=True)
```

I seem to always run into issues when trying to perform seemingly basic things with these spatially enabled dataframes.

Comment: You could use the arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion tool https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/json-to-features.htm and remove the need for pandas and GeoAccessor

Comment: @Clubdebambos thank you for your comment. I though of trying to leverage that tool but I think that would require a download of the json data first before conversion. I believe it does not support data streams if I'm not mistaken. Or in other words, data pulled from an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue after updating ArcGIS Pro and arcpy to v2.9.  Basically if the SEDF did not have a geometry column named "SHAPE" (all caps) then the `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 42 elements, new values have 41 elements` error was thrown.

Try renaming your geometry column from "shape" to "SHAPE".

Implementing something like this into your workflow should solve permanently.

```
if geo_column != 'SHAPE':
    df.rename(columns={geo_column: "SHAPE"}, inplace=True)
sedf = GeoAccessor.from_df(
  df=df,
  sr=sr, 
  geometry_column="SHAPE",    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to have arcpy to use `from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor`.
Try this:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor

fc = r"<FEATURE_CLASS_PATH>"
df = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_featureclass(fc)
```